# JDBC prepared statement UTF-8

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, utf-8

Continuing my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060720/jsp-upload-file-with-utf-8-encoding

I discovered that when i do:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crm2?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection (url, MY_USERNAME, MY_PASSWORD);

PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
.
.
.

pst.setString(1, customer.getFullName());
.
.
.
pst.executeUpdate();
```

I got the following SQL exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(`name` = '?…?±?ˆ?§?†'

As you can see i mentioned in the connection string too use encoding utf-8!
looks like i have to do something else in the PST to insure using UTF-8?

Thanks

Comment: what is sql probably the reason of the error is that sql is null or wrong

Comment: This is the SQL: String sql = "Update lead set (`name` = ?,`status` = ?,`country` = ?,`campaign` = ?,`age` = ?,`language`=?,`email`=?,'phone'=?,'mobile'=?) where `lead_id` = ?"; but as mentioned before the problem was with the encoding for me, please notice the error message is converting the name to some other encoding

Comment: Start by removing those quotes around phone and mobile anyway.

Comment: dude!! please understand the question! I know about that problem in the SQL but what i'm saying is why the prepared statement is converting my arabic input letters in the name field into another format!!

Comment: dude!! if you posted actual, correct Java code, which actually compiles and uses correct SQL, along with the full stack trace of the exception you get, we would not suspect that the problem is in fact caused by something you don't show us, and we wouldn't have to guess what the code is.

Comment: I can't understand why you are saying that, I wanted to post a not working SQL to show you the exception and show you how my string looks like inside the message that is comming back from the side of MYSQL so the not correct SQL was posted in purpose!! I hope you understand me well now ... dude!

Comment: Post your real code. It's as simple as that. With the full exception stack trace. There shouldn't be quotes around column names, and I suspected that this might be the cause of your problem, that's why I told you to remove them. I'm forced to guess where the problem could come from, because you don't provide valid code, you don't provide a valid SQL query, and you don't provide the exception stack trace. Have you at least tried removing these quotes?

Comment: @JBNizet: Actually, the opening parenthesis (`(`) following the SET keyword is enough to trigger the error. Marwan: Have you verified that your Java source code file is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: I think you are not able to understand what i'm saying!  maybe the my english is not describing what i wanted to say maybe other reason, so I'm describing again the SQL is wrong because i wanted it to print the exception so i can see the encoded name! why this is hard to be understood! anyway thank you for your help i really appreciate your time @gord-thompson thanks for your help it's exactly were the problem was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading and writing to a database with UTF-8 data it is important that the Java source code file be encoded as UTF-8. Otherwise, strange things can happen when we start manipulating strings that we receive from (or send to) the database.

Comment: Thanks alot :) you just gave me an excuse to sleep tonight :D